# How can I delete an object and capture the deletion of the object event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, global

There are two things I am trying to do:

1. delete an object whether a const or let - right way to do it in node.js
2. capture the delete or assignation of null or undefined to cInst or dInst object in the global scope. I do not want to wrap the global or globalThis objects inside an object or closure object to get this done.

Is there a way to do it?

```
'use strict';

function TestBase() {};
let dInst = TestBase();
delete dInst; // fails with use strict
dInst = undefined // works
```

```
const cInst = TestBase();
delete cInst; // works without use strict
```

```
'use strict';

const cInst = TestBase();
delete cInst; // fails without use strict
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @evolutionxbox register a on destroy callback

Answer (score 2):

1. There's no way to delete objects explicitly, objects are automatically deleted by the garbage collector when all references go away. If the only reference to the object is a single variable, simply reassigning the variable will delete it; if it's a local variable, returning from the function will cause it to be deleted.
2. See [Finalization Registry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/FinalizationRegistry) for the documentation of how to register a callback to be notified when an object is deleted by GC.

Comment: let me try this

Comment: I am looking at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/FinalizationRegistry#callbacks_never_called_synchronously what is the .register(target, heldValue) used for? seems the target has to be type object and does not take primitive vlues

Comment: See the [official specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/managing-memory.html#sec-finalization-registry.prototype.register). It references the concept [CanBeHeldWeakly](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/executable-code-and-execution-contexts.html#sec-canbeheldweakly)